Old Game show in which contestants named ingredients
I recall a Food Channel Network type show from a bunch of years ago (10? more?) It was a game show with the standard question/answer rounds about food trivia. One round might even have involved naming foods in a category or deciding if a partuclar esoteric food belonged in one category or another. 
The final round had the 2 remaining contestants eating the same food and having to name the ingredients. One would name an ingredient and then the other, and then back and forth until one missed 3 times (IIRC).
I looked at the wikipedia list of 226 shows which had been created by Food Network as of 2009 but since I don't know the name I didn't start looking at every single one.
Does anyone know the name of the show? TIA

Reminds me of Super Market Sweep (not the show you're asking about). I don't recall any shows on food network so it will be interesting to see what it turns out to be.

Possibly the Food Network's short-lived Pressure Cooker from 1998, where 3 contestants answered food trivia questions in the first round and the 2 remaining contestants competed in a '3 strikes & you're out' ingredient taste-off. The winning contestant then went on to a bonus round. There's an episode on Youtube in 2 parts: Part 1 & Part 2 (that starts with the taste-off).
If this still isn't it, the Wiki page says the show was later renamed 'Taste Test' and retained the taste-off round, but I was unable to find any clips from it.
